# Netsuite - on creation of a record using webservices cannot add new line item to database

Tags: javascript, netsuite, enterprise

On creation of a Netsuite record, I'm attempting to add a description line item to the sublist of the record.

I have tried to trigger the script that is adding the line item on before record submit and after record submit.

The script is firing yet the nlapiInsertLineItem function is not inserting a line.

It works perfectly on on 'edit', but for some reason not on 'create'.

Does anyone have experience inserting a new line item on creation of a record in Netsuite?

I should mention this record is being created by webservices.

Thanks for your help!

My code currently as is:

```
function optiv_SFquote_visibility_AS(type){
  if(type == 'create'){
    var recId = nlapiGetRecordId();
    var recType = nlapiGetRecordType();
    var rec = nlapiLoadRecord(recType, recId);
    var itemCnt = rec.getLineItemCount('item');
    var soVals = {};
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= itemCnt+j; i ++){
        var grpNum = rec.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_grp_num', i);
        if(isNotNull(grpNum) && soVals[grpNum] == undefined){
            soVals[grpNum] = grpNum;
            j++;
            var grpDscrpt = rec.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_sf_quote_dscrpt', i);
            var grpName = rec.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_grp_sf_name', i);
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'group description', grpDscrpt + ' name ' + grpName);
            var newDscrpt = '';
            if(isNotNull(grpDscrpt) && isNotNull(grpName)){
                var newDscrpt = grpName + ' - ' + grpDscrpt;
            }
            else if(isNotNull(grpName) && isNull(grpDscrpt)){
                var newDscrpt = grpName;
            }
            rec.insertLineItem('item', i);
            rec.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', i, -3);
            rec.setLineItemValue('item', 'description', i, newDscrpt);
        }
    }
    nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an similar situation where we add a line item to a sales order if it contains a value in a specific field.  It is executing on `beforeSubmit` when a sales order is created.  We're not using the full `nlapiInsertLineItem()` function, but the `insertLineItem()` function that can be found on `nlobjRecord`.

```
function addFreightLine(freightInstructions) {
    var record = nlapiGetNewRecord();
    var newLineNum = record.getLineItemCount('item') + 1;

    record.insertLineItem('item', newLineNum);
    record.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', newLineNum, 733);   // 733 is the 'CF' item
    record.setLineItemValue('item', 'description', newLineNum, freightInstructions);
    record.setLineItemValue('item', 'rate', newLineNum, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response! Is the addFreightLine function the one being called beforeSubmit? My script is still not inserting the line item even if calling insertLineItem off the nlobjRecord beforeSubmit. You said this is firing on create of the record; do you know what execution context the record is being created off of? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, addFeightLine() is being called beforeSubmit on the create event for sales orders. Can you update your question with a sample of your code?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. I have updated my question with my code. Currently it is running on afterSubmit and I am submitting the nlobjRecord to database with nlapiSubmitRecord. Again, it is working on 'edit' and on not on 'create'. It also works on execution context 'userinterface' but not on execution context 'webservices'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're loading and submitting the record when you don't need to.  Use nlapiGetNewRecord() rather than nlapiLoadRecord().   This gives you access to the newly updated record before it's committed to the database.  Also, remove nlapiSubmitRecord().  NetSuite will handle that for you in a beforeSubmit.  The assumption is that NetSuite is going to submit it's just giving you an opportunity to change the data before it does.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have tried your solution when I originally saw your first post. I have tried loading nlobjRecord from nlapiGetNewRecord() and called insertLineItem and setLineItemValue off current record object and excluded the nlapiSubmitRecord() because beforeSubmit automatically submits record to database. Honestly, I think it has something to do with the fact that we are creating the Netsuite record with execution context 'webservices'. Your solution works perfectly when we create the record manually in Netsuite. But that is not the problem; it malfunctions when record is created etxernally.

Comment: Here's a link to my exact function that is adding a line item to a sales order.  All of our sales orders are created via NetSuite's web service API.  https://gist.github.com/mdrobbins/476fd2bc0e073e4d8de054b7dcb64b74